# Por que minhas rotas só funcionam no localhost e não em server Web?

Tags: php, mvc, route

Sou desenvolvedor **.NET** (Apps desktop & mobiles) tentando entrar pra web que achei melhor o **PHP** por ser uma Lang livre e seus IDE's serem levinhos. Criei meu pattern MVC (por ser iniciante preferi não usar frameworks) e na máquina local tá show de bola. Mas ***por quê quando migro ele para um server dá problema nas rotas?*** Parou de mudar de página, só mantem o DEFAULT (Home).
Que tem de errado no meu código?

```
    public static function route($url) {

        // my default controller
        define('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER', 'Home');

        // controller
        $controller = (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != '') ? ucwords($url[0]) : DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
        $controller_name = $controller;
        array_shift($url);

        // action
        $action = (isset($url[0]) && $url[0] != '') ? $url[0] . 'Action': 'indexAction';
        $action_name = $controller;
        array_shift($url);

        $queryParams = $url;

        $dispatch = new $controller($controller_name, $action);

        if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
            call_user_func_array([$dispatch, $action], $queryParams);
        } else {
            header("Location: ../_404");
        }
    }

}
```

Ficheiro .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond $1 !^(config|core|css|js|fonts|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As vezes o problema não está no código, e sim na configuração do `htaccess` ou servidor.

Comment: Esse dai meu htaccess, vejo erro nenhum ou deve tar faltando flags? Meu Server n usa a pasta public ja botei ate RewriteBase / mesmo assim nada!


`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond $1 !^(config|core|css|js|fonts|robots\.txt)`

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: seu servidor web é apache ou ngix?

Comment: Olá @WillKnippelberg, obrigado por tirar tempo para responder, na verdade meu problema já foi solucionado. Estava rodando um servidor Apache e meu erro estava no arquivo `.htaccess`.